# Laravel 8 Swift_IoException Unable to open file for reading

Tags: laravel-8

working with Laravel 8 project. I have developed contact form sending email by submit the form button as well. this is working properly in my localhost but when I host files to the live server when click contact submit form it is encountering following error in the page.
`Swift_IoException Unable to open file for reading [/home3/malsi/xxx/public/images/logo.png]`

UserController.php

```
$user = new User;

        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->telephone = $request->input('telephone');
        $user->message = $request->input('message');
        
        $user->save();

        $verifyUser = VerifyUser::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'token' => Str::random(40)
        ]);

        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new VerifyMail($user));
return redirect('/#contact')->with('info', 'We sent you an activation code. Check your email and click on the link to verify');
```

public_html/index.php

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../xxx/bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
)->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

how could I fix this problem here?

I need some solutions for this problem